# Tkinter Output Blurry for icon and Text Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have trawled the net and can't seem to find a satisfactory answer. Whenever I run a program that has a Tkinter GUI it always seems blurry/fuzzy (which I assume is a low resolution). It seems much lower resolution than the Windows 10 OS that is running on a couple of computers that I run these programs on.

It doesn't matter what program I run I still get the same results for all types of Tkinter entities such as buttons, labels, file dialogues etc. Which is why I have not included a sample of code.

I have copied some examples below:

[Tkinter FD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKZUQ.png)

[Tkinter Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb3fR.png)

Is this something I should just expect or is there some of setting on the OS\Python\Tkinter that I need to alter.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I have tried this on another Windows 10 computer and the output is fine. The other computer is just a very basic Minix z64. I am wondering if it is because the other two computers have a graphics card, but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be an OS tweak. I don't know the details (would be glad for an explanataion), but it does the job on Windows 10:

```
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
```

Call it before you initiate your GUI, i.e.:

```
import ctypes
.
.
.
if __name__ == "__main__":   
    if 'win' in sys.platform:
        ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

    [call your Tkinter stuff]
```

Got it from here:

[Attempting to resolve blurred tkinter text + scaling on Windows 10 high DPI displays, but concerned my approach is not Pythonic or is unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315873/attempting-to-resolve-blurred-tkinter-text-scaling-on-windows-10-high-dpi-disp)

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. I fixed it by disabling display scaling on high DPI settings on python.exe and pythonw.exe.

I followed the instructions on this page: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fonts-appear-blurred-windows-8

1) Open your Python installation directory, this should be `C:\Python27\`

2) Find a executable file called `python.exe`

3) Right click it, and select properties

4) Go to the compatibility tab, and check `Disable display scaling on high DPI settings`

5) Repeat for pythonw.exe

This should fix your issues with blurry fonts

Answer (score 0):

I was able so solve it! I had a look on this question: [on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43046744/19152419) The answer from [@Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5387972/jay) solved my problem completely. So it was not really a tkinter/python thing, but rather windows itself.