# Window resolution in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I know that this might sound weird, but I have a problem considering the screen resolution of my Tkinter program. I have attached two pictures for a comparison.

[image: Good quality]

[image: Bad quality]

I think you can clearly tell, what I'm talking about. The problem is that I don't really know why this happened. Suddenly the tkinter window had a way better resolution as you can see in the top picture. I did not change anything related to screensize/resolution by myself and was therefore expecting Tkinter to have published an update which just has better textures for every widget.
But because I had to reinstall python and all its modules this is no longer the case and the widgets look very blurry again (Bottom picture). Now I'm asking myself whether this has something to do with another version of Python or tkinter I'm using or what else could have been the reason for that.
I did not change my PC, Screen or anything like that. I just reinstalled python and its modules. Sadly I don't have the source code of the version where it looked great, but only an .exe file, because im continuously updating my program. But as I said before, I don't know what I could have changed which led to this huge resolution improvement.

I hope you get, what I'm trying to tell you.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In *older versions* of tkinter it helped for windows to set `windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)` but I read its not necessary anymore. But I would try. [take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52599951/13629335)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tip, I have also read about that and tried it. Yes, it does help to some extend but also not that well. I was just asking myself, what was causing this improvement in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried to set the Properties to high dpi settings as the second answer recommends?

Comment: This has always happened to me when on a new OS, I had to go display settings and untick let windows fix blurry apps, and set custom scale factor too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able so solve it!
I had a look on this question: [on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315873/attempting-to-resolve-blurred-tkinter-text-scaling-on-windows-10-high-dpi-disp)
The answer from @binaryfunt solved my problem completely. So it was not really a tkinter/python thing, but rather windows itself.