# Tkinter Output Blurry for icon python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.iconbitmap

I have trawled the net and can't seem to find a satisfactory answer. Whenever I run a program that has a Tkinter GUI it always seems blurry/fuzzy (which I assume is a low resolution).

[See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbLCp.png)

I saw a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514158/tkinter-output-blurry-for-icon-and-text-python-2-7) and that solves the problem with the fonts dpi. But still the icon looks trash like 16x16. How to improve that?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: found any solution? if so please post it as answer